# how do I get the intersection of two arrays INCLUDING identical elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
apple = ["a","p","p"]
zebra = ["a","p","p","l","e"]
apple & zebra
# returns => ["a", "p"]
```

I want a function that returns ["a","p","p"]

is there any method that can do this?

Comment: already answered there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020334/ruby-array-intersection-with-duplicates. Use `(apple & zebra).flat_map { |n| [n]*[apple.count(n), zebra.count(n)].min }`

Comment: what is the intended result if one or the other has only 1 p?

Comment: This works for your example. No idea if it works generally as the rules aren't so clear to me `apple.select { |i| zebra.include? i }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 : This is wrong, for example with `app` and `aple`.

Comment: @EricDuminil my fault, you were right

Comment: @fl00r The duplicate question has a faster implementation for big arrays.

Comment: @engineersmnky: `intersection` makes it pretty clear. Only 1 p should be returned.

Comment: The selected answer at the dup question looks quite good.