# Find exact value overlap between two arrays

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays

```
a1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
a2 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

I want to return the values that appear in both arrays AND the exact amount that they appear

```
# => [1, 1, 3, 3]
```

I can't use `a1 & a2` because that will return unique values (`[1, 3]`)

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you have there are not really arrays, they are [*multisets*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or *bags*.

There is a general rule in programming: if you choose your data representation right, your algorithms become simpler.

So, if you use multisets instead of arrays, your problem will become trivial, since what you are looking for is literally just the intersection of two multisets.

Unfortunately, there is no multiset implementation in the core or standard libraries, but there are a couple of multiset gems available on the web. For example, there is the [multimap gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/multimap), which also includes a multiset. Unfortunately, it needs a little bit of love and care, since it uses a C extension that only works until YARV 2.2. There is also the [multiset gem](https://maraigue.hhiro.net/multiset/).

```ruby
require 'multiset'

m1 = Multiset.new(a1)
#=> #<Multiset:#3 1, #1 2, #3 3>

m2 = Multiset.new(a2)
#=> #<Multiset:#2 1, #2 3, #2 5>

m = m1 & m2
#=> #<Multiset:#2 1, #2 3>
```

Personally, I am not too big a fan of the `inspect` output, but we can see what's going on and that the result is correct: `m` contains 2 × `1` and 2 × `3`.

If you really need the result as an `Array`, you can use [`Multiset#to_a`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/multiset/Multiset#to_a-instance_method):

```ruby
m.to_a
#=> [1, 1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Just in case the upvoter reads this: I moved the answer to the dupe target at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69119472/2988 and am going to delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

At first I do get the intersection between a1 and a2 with `(a1 & a2)`. After that I iterate over the intersection and check which array has a lower count of each element. The element gets than added to the result array as many times as it occurs in the array with the lower count using `result.fill`

```rb
a1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
a2 = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5]

result = []
(a1 & a2).each do |e|
    a1.count(e) < a2.count(e) ? result.fill(e, result.size, a1.count(e)) : result.fill(e, result.size, a2.count(e))
end

pp result
```

Comment: What would be the time complexity of this? I _think_ it can be done in linear time (+ sorting, if arrays are not guaranteed to be sorted). For small array, it doesn't matter much, but still it's a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: The question from @Naoki Mi seems to be a duplicate and I already flagged it, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020334/ruby-array-intersection-with-duplicates) There you can find also discussions regarding time complexity